# Cross Domain AJAX POST 403 forbidden when attempting to execute a cs WebMethod

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, cross-domain, cors

Pardon my noobiness in web development terminology.

I am trying to execute the following [WebMethod]:

```
public static void CreatePendingCaseFromChat(string userInputs)
{
    //Do a bunch of stuff here with the userInputs string
}
```

With the following AJAX (which resides on another server):

```
$.ajax({    type: "POST", 
            url: "http://www.MyCoolWebDomain.com/Code/MyCode.aspx/CreatePendingCaseFromChat",
            crossDomain: true,
            data: JSON.stringify(parameters), 
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data){alert("success in ajax call")}, 
            error: function (data){alert("error in ajax call")}
        });
```

MyCode.aspx contains the following lines within the Page_Load() method:

```
Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); //Allow Cross domain AJAX call, update the "*" to be a specific URL
Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS");
Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "content-type, x-requested-with");
```

If I do the following, instead of the ajax call:

```
var invocation = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://www.MyCoolWebDomain.com/Code/MyCode.aspx/CreatePendingCaseFromChat"
if (invocation) {
    invocation.open('POST', url, false);
    invocation.send();
    }
else {
    alert("no invocation");
}
```

Then I can confirm with FireBug that the following Response Headers are set:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Head...    content-type, x-requested-with
Access-Control-Allow-Meth...    GET, POST, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Orig...    *
```

With the AJAX call, none of those headers are shown.

I would like to make this work either way, whether with the AJAX call, or with the XHR call.

For the XHR call I can't figure out how to send the userInputs string to the WebMethod.
For the AJAX call I can't get it passed preflight or w/e it's called (the OPTIONS call).

Comment: show the decorators on the cs method from the page that contains it. - and you will need to use jsonp methinks

Comment: @Mark Schultheiss This is where my noobiness comes in. How do I show the decorators; what are the decorators?

Also, I tried JSONP, but it only works with "GET", and I assumed (possibly incorrectly) that because I want to pass a string to my WebMethod, I need to use "POST"?

Comment: for JSON I'm pretty sure you need the [ScriptService] and [ScriptMethod] decorators

Comment: Do you see the OPTIONS request go out in FireBug? If so, you need something on your service layer to respond to the OPTION request with a 200 and the _Access-Control-Allow_ headers you specified above.

Comment: this is one example of a decorater you would need for sure: [WebMethod]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've posted a bunch of code on question:

[CORS - Ajax error function reports error code as 0 for an API request returning 401](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14268706/cors-ajax-error-function-reports-error-code-as-0-for-an-api-request-returning)

It is using MVC4, but should give you everything you need to get this working.