# CORS - Ajax error function reports error code as 0 for an API request returning 401

Tags: ajax, jquery, cors

### Background

I have CORS working in my local dev environment when authentication (JWT) succeeds. I have the client page running off of localhost and calling into api.mycompany.com for data.
My api project checks for a valid JWT, and if it passes, returns the content. It took me a while to get here, but this all works fine.

If I do not send a valid JWT, the api responds properly with a 401 (checked this in Fiddler), but the error function callback on the client reports an error code of 0 and a status of "error".

I want the ajax callback function to check the status code of the error and if it is 401, check the headers for a header named location (which will contain the uri to the authentication service).

### Setup

- (API Project) Visual Studio 2012 instance running MVC4 project on local IIS Express

  - Local host file maps 127.0.0.1 to api.mycompany.com
  - Set Project -> Properties -> Web to IIS Express

    - Use Local IIS Express (checked)
    - Project Url: `http://localhost:8080`
    - Created Virtual Directory
    - Override application root URL (checked)
    - Override application root URL: `http://api.mycompany.com:8080`
  - In applicationhost.config under sites:

    ```
    <site name="StuffManagerAPI" id="1">
      <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
        <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Users\me\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\StuffManagerAPI\StuffManagerAPI" />
      </application>
      <bindings>
        <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:8080:localhost" />
        <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:8080:api.mycompany.com" />
      </bindings>
    </site>
    ```
- (Client Project) Separate Visual Studio Instance with ASP.net empty web application

  - Set Project -> Properties -> Web to IIS Express

    - Use Local IIS Express (checked)
    - Project Url: `http://localhost:22628`
    - Created Virtual Directory
- Using Google Chrome as the test client
- Using Fiddler to view traffic

### Code

I think these should be the important bits from my Proof of Concept. Once again, the CORS preflight and data retrieval all work fine. It's just the unauthorized case that is not working. If you need anything else, please let me know. Thanks for the help.

#### API Project

**Authorization Header Handler**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace StuffManagerAPI.Handlers
{
public class AuthorizationHeaderHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private const string KEY = "theKey";

    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<HttpResponseMessage>();

        const string identityProviderUri = "https://idp.mycompany.com";

        IEnumerable<string> apiKeyHeaderValues = null;
        if (request.Headers.TryGetValues("Authorization", out apiKeyHeaderValues))
        {
            var apiKeyHeaderValue = apiKeyHeaderValues.First();
            var token = apiKeyHeaderValue.Split(' ').LastOrDefault();
            var tokenProcessor = new JasonWebTokenDecryptor.JasonWebToken(token, KEY);

            if (tokenProcessor.IsValid)
            {
                base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken).ContinueWith(t => taskCompletionSource.SetResult(t.Result));
            }
            else
            {
                var response = FailedResponseWithAddressToIdentityProvider(identityProviderUri);
                taskCompletionSource.SetResult(response);
            }

        }
        else
        {
            if(request.Method.Method != "OPTIONS")
            {
                //No Authorization Header therefore needs to redirect
                var response = FailedResponseWithAddressToIdentityProvider(identityProviderUri);
                taskCompletionSource.SetResult(response);
            }
            else
            {
                base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken).ContinueWith(t => taskCompletionSource.SetResult(t.Result));
            }
        }

        return taskCompletionSource.Task;
    }

    private static HttpResponseMessage FailedResponseWithAddressToIdentityProvider(string identityProviderUri)
    {
        // Create the response.
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
        response.Headers.Add("Location", identityProviderUri);
        return response;
    }
}
}
```

**Stuff Controller**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web.Http;
using StuffManagerAPI.Attributes;
using StuffManagerAPI.Models;

namespace StuffManagerAPI.Controllers
{
[HttpHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")]
[HttpHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "OPTIONS, HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE")]
[HttpHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization")]
[HttpHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Location")]
public class StuffController : ApiController
{
    private readonly Stuff[] _stuff = new[]
        {
            new Stuff
                {
                    Id = "123456",
                    SerialNumber = "112233",
                    Description = "Cool Item"
                },
            new Stuff
                {
                    Id = "456789",
                    SerialNumber = "445566",
                    Description = "Another Cool Item"
                }
        };

    public Stuff Get(string id)
    {
        var item = _stuff.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);
        if (item == null)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }

        return item;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Stuff> GetAll()
    {
        return _stuff;
    }

    public void Options()
    {
       // nothing....
    }

}
}
```

#### Client Project

**main.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>ASP.NET Web API</title>
    <link href="../Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var baseUrl = "http://api.mycompany.com:8080/api/";
        $.support.cors = true;

        $(document).ready(
            getListofStuff()
        );

        function setHeader(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('authorization', 'Bearer blah.blah.blah');
        }

        function getListofStuff() {
            var apiUrl = baseUrl + "stuff/";

            $.ajax({
                url: apiUrl,
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                crossDomain: true,
                success: receivedListOfStuff,
                error: receiveError,
                beforeSend: setHeader,
                statusCode: {
                    0: function() {
                        alert('got 0');
                    },
                    401: function () {
                        alert('finally got a 401');
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        function getIndividualPieceOfStuff(id) {
            var apiUrl = baseUrl + "stuff/" + id;

            $.ajax({
                url: apiUrl,
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                crossDomain: true,
                success: receivedIndividualStuffItem,
                error: receiveError,
                beforeSend: setHeader
            });
        }

        function receivedListOfStuff(data) {
            $.each(data, function (key, val) {

                var listItem = $('<li/>').text(val.Description);
                listItem.data("content", { id: val.Id});
                $(".myStuff").prepend(listItem);
            });

            $(".myStuff li").click(function () {
                getIndividualPieceOfStuff($(this).data("content").id);
            });
        }

        function receivedIndividualStuffItem(data) {
            $("#stuffDetails #id").val(data.Id);
            $("#stuffDetails #serialNumber").val(data.SerialNumber);
            $("#stuffDetails #description").val(data.Description);
        }

        function receiveError(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            var x = xhr.getResponseHeader("Location");
            var z = xhr.responseText;

            if (xhr.status == 401){
                alert('finally got a 401');
               }

            alert('Error AJAX');
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
.
.
.
.
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Figured I should test in other browsers as well....Firefox returns 0, IE 8 gets the 401. Odd

Comment: I'm surprised by the response from IE8. But in general, most browsers give very little information to help debug CORS requests. You can at best know that an error occurred, but nothing else (status code is 0, status text is empty). See a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844643/is-it-possible-to-trap-cors-errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally figured it out. In the Authorization Header Handler, when tokenProcessor.IsValid is false, I jump to FailedResponseWithAddressToIdentityProvider and then immediately set the result and mark the task as complete. Therefore, I never visit the Stuff Controller and get the Access Control Headers added:

```
if (tokenProcessor.IsValid)
{
    base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken).ContinueWith(t => taskCompletionSource.SetResult(t.Result));
}
else
{
    var response = FailedResponseWithAddressToIdentityProvider(identityProviderUri);
            taskCompletionSource.SetResult(response);
}
.
.
.
private static HttpResponseMessage FailedResponseWithAddressToIdentityProvider(string identityProviderUri)
{
    // Create the response.
    var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
    response.Headers.Add("Location", identityProviderUri);
    return response;
}
```

}

There is probably a better way to do this, but I simply added the headers to my response in the FailedResponseWithAddressToIdentityProvider method and the browser finally sees the 401 in Chrome, Firefox, and IE8. Here is the change:

```
private static HttpResponseMessage FailedResponseWithAddressToIdentityProvider(string identityProviderUri)
{
    // Create the response.
    var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
    response.Headers.Add("Location", identityProviderUri);
    response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "OPTIONS, HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
    response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization");
    response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Location");
    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather checking status code directly on ajax can you check that on onComplete using this code...

```
> $.ajaxSetup({
>     error: function (x) {     
>         if (x.status == 401) {
>             alert("401");
>         }
>     } });
```

Comment: I tried the code and placed a break point on the if statement. x.status still comes back as 0 in Chrome and Firefox. However, as I mentioned in my comment, IE8 does comes back with '401'

Comment: okey than in that case try to detect request in failure function whether it is ajax request ...!! "Request.IsAjaxRequest()" and if it is ajx then return with you desired httpstatuscode

Comment: Sorry, I am not following that recommendation. My server is responding with a proper http status code of 401 whether it is an ajax request or non-ajax request.