# WebAPI, HTTPS and CORS

Tags: json, https, asp.net-web-api, cors

Been struggling to get this working, basically Im trying to submit JSON to a WebAPI controller in my project.

Ive added a "CorsHandler" to handle the OPTIONS request and the data is successfully being sent cross domain, so far so good.

The thing is when I add the attribute "ApiHttps" I get an error back from the browser.

```
OPTIONS https://localhost:44302/Api/Form/Submit/1 Resource failed to load
```

The ApiHttps class is this

```
public class ApiHttps : AuthorizationFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (actionContext.Request.RequestUri.Scheme != Uri.UriSchemeHttps && actionContext.Request.Method != HttpMethod.Options)
        {
            actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
            {
                ReasonPhrase = "HTTPS Required"
            };
        }
        else
        {
            base.OnAuthorization(actionContext);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there something I am doing wrong or have over looked?

I just need to be able to send json data cross domain via https :-) if you need any more info just ask!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I've posted a bunch of code on question:

[CORS - Ajax error function reports error code as 0 for an API request returning 401](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14268706/cors-ajax-error-function-reports-error-code-as-0-for-an-api-request-returning)

It is using MVC4, but should give you everything you need to get this working (except for the authentication aspect my question is asking)