# CORS request fails in Chrome only if has headers

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome, http-headers, cors

I'm trying to send simple CORS request to external application server which uses session key for authorization.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://192.168.1.72:8442/api/file/",
    headers: {"Authorization": "3238562439e44fcab4036a24a1e6b0fb"}
});
```

It works fine in Firefox 18, Opera 12.12 and Rekonq 2.0 (uses also WebKit) but doesn't work in Google Chrome (tried versions 21 and 24). In Google Chrome it shows OPTIONS Resource failed to load in Network Inspector and application server doesn't get any request. I've tried jQuery 1.8.3 and 1.9.0.

```
Request URL:https://192.168.1.72:8442/api/file/
Request Headers
Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, authorization, origin
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
Cache-Control:no-cache
Origin:https://192.168.1.72:8480
Pragma:no-cache
```

If I remove headers from the request then I receive 401 also in Google Chrome and it's able to access the resource in case of authorization is disabled on application server. It doesn't matter which headers are sent. Only header I'm able to send is {"Content-Type": "plain/text"}. All other header names/values give an error in Google Chrome but work in all browsers I mentioned above.

Why Google Chrome doesn't handle headers in CORS request?

Comment: Try `authorization` with a common `a`

Comment: Can you list the request and response headers for the OPTIONS request? The server should be responding with the following:
    `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`
    `Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE`
    `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: accept, authorization, origin`

Comment: @monsur: I had all these headers already. I've also tried to add more allowed headers and methods but it didn't help.

Comment: What is the error that Chrome is giving you?

Comment: @monsur: In Network Inspector: `OPTIONS Resource failed to load`. 
Ajax error response: `{"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"}`

Comment: I tested ajax request above on my Android 2.3.7 mobile. It worked flawlessy with Opera Mobile but failed with default Google's browser.

Comment: Pure XMLHttpRequest also fails in Chrome if request has headers. All other browsers work fine.

`var invocation = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = 'https://192.168.1.72:8442/api/file/';
if(invocation) {
    invocation.open('GET', url, true);
    invocation.setRequestHeader('authorization', '3238562439e44fcab4036a24a1e6b0fb');
    invocation.send();
}`

Comment: I had a similar issue because I was returning a non-standard header in my response and had to add to allow access-control on the response header with: Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Location

Comment: @Erds: I added all response headers to Access-Control-Expose-Headers and it still doesn't work in Chrome.

Comment: I don't know then. I have it working with all browsers with my code in question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14268706/cors-ajax-error-function-reports-error-code-as-0-for-an-api-request-returning
Maybe it will help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's a bug in Google Chrome: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=96007.

Comment: FYI that bug was closed Oct 2015.

Comment: I have a similar problem, my application is built using Angular 7. I am making an ajax call to a BPMS server which works fine in IE but I have a CORS error in Chrome. However when I copy the ajax url to the Chrome browser I have all the data. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4):

I found that Access-Control-Allow-Headers: * should be set ONLY for "OPTIONS" request.
If you return it for POST request then browser cancel the request (at least for chrome)

The following PHP code works for me

```
// Allow CORS
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');    
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS"); 

// Access-Control headers are received during OPTIONS requests
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");
}
```

I found similar questions with some misleading response:
- Server thread says that this is 2 years bug of chrome: Access-Control-Allow-Headers does not match with localhost. It's wrong: I can use CORS to my local server with Post normally
- Access-Control-Allow-Headers does accept wildcards. It's also wrong, wildcard works for me (I tested only with Chrome)

This take me half day to figure out the issue.

Happy coding

Answer (score 3):

I'm using self-signed certificate on my api server and that seems to be the issue. I found that if I start Google Chrome with `--disable-web-security` option, then CORS with request headers is working. Without `--disable-web-security` I can send CORS requests to self-signed api server but can't add any headers (except Content-Type).

Comment: The same problem happens with one domain connecting to another domain (both using http). Your --disable-web-security option fixes that case too. I believe *that* bug is specific to EventSource, and might be fixed in Chrome 26. However `--disable-web-security` did not fix the self-signed cert HTTPS problem (whether using EventSource or XMLHttpResponse), at least not in Chrome 25.

Answer (score 1):

**Server side**:
The server should set the header "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" and also set the allowed headers in "Access-Control-Allow-Headers".

**Client side**: You can set xhrFields in $.ajax() instead of explicitly passing Auth header.

```
xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true 
}
```

More details [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/).

Comment: withCredentials seems to be for cookies or basic auth. I just wanna get request headers working in Chrome.