# CORS XMLHTTPRequest not working in Chromium 28

Tags: ajax, cors

I am trying to send CORS AJAX requests but it seems to fail :

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "http://enable-cors.org");
xhr.addEventListener("load", function() { console.log(this.responseText); });
xhr.send();
```

I am making this request from the console, while browsing http://stackoverflow.com.

I get this error message :

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://enable-cors.org/. Origin http://stackoverflow.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

I believe enable-cors.org should send back correct `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers :)
But this holds true for any other website.

Also the `console` tells me an Origin header has been properly sent in my request.

I am using Chromium 28, but Firefox fails too.

**HTTP request headers are :**

```
Request URL:http://enable-cors.org/
Origin:http://stackoverflow.com
Referer:http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18303449/edit
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.95 Safari/537.36
```

What do I do wrong ?

Comment: Is this any help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14492686/cors-request-fails-in-chrome-only-if-has-headers

Comment: Lets see the request and response headers.

Comment: I updated with request headers. Response headers are "not available" in the console (is the request not even sent by Chromium ?). I don't think this is Chromium specific since last version of Firefox fails too.

Comment: However I tried with http://remysharp.com/demo/cors.php, and it works. I might just be targeting a website which is not CORS-enabled (although it surprises me from enable-cors.org).

Comment: what you are trying to do here? why you are trying to connect to http://enable-cors.org and what response do u expect?

Comment: I am trying to download the HTML content of any CORS-enabled page, and thought enable-cors.org would have CORS-enabled page. But I'm realized maybe it's not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure the response headers are available.  Most likely you are just not looking in the correct place.  I suspect you are looking at the "response" tab, instead of in the "headers" tab.  Either way, I looked at a request/response to/from enable-cors.org myself, and it is clear that this site does not permit cross-origin requests due to the lack of "Access-Control-*" headers in the response.  So, you are out of luck.

By the way, why are you trying to make cross-origin requests to enable-cors.org anyway?  It's a static site.  It's primary purpose is to teach others about CORS.  I think it might be nice to provide some sort of a "sandbox" that lets learners test out CORS themselves though.  Maybe that is something you can suggest in the forum related to the site.  Click on the "suggest" link in nav bar.